Algorithms for signal shape detection
I have a discrete signal shape which I am trying to find in accelerometer data. I want to compare at least two methods. First one is of course correlation, I calculate peak value of 10  experiments and take an average on that. But I also need some more algorithms, that are good at detecting similarity between two signal shapes. Any suggestions? I will add my template signal for reference


Maybe this can be of interest to you, even though it might be overkill for your purposes.
